# Google Cloud VPS network traffic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a Google Cloud Compute Engine Windows VPS. I wanted to know that if i try to upload files on Google Drive from VPS will it charge me network fees.

as per the chart below I thought it will not because google cloud VPS and Google Drive is from Google and utilizing other google services from VPS is free. Please tell me if i am wrong? just wanted to confirm

[image: trafic]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right.

Network Egress traffic to Google products (such as YouTube, Maps, Drive), whether from a VM in GCP with a public (external) IP addresses or private (internal) IP addresses has no charge

[General network pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#general).

I know it used to be a promotional price but now it's in the General network pricing list as 'No charge'.